# C# dt.Compute() Don't work properly on some multiplications

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, int

Good Day,

I have a problem with dt.Compute() in C#.

The Problem is that when I'm trying to calculate something like that: 500'000*5'000 than I get a:

> System.OverflowException: " value was either too large or too small
>   for an 'int32'."

The Result should be: 2'500'000'000 but c# get this result: -2146233066
and thats to small for int32.

It's working when I'm trying to Calculate 5*5 or 5'000'000'000 * 5'000'000 but when I try to calculate something like 5'000'000'000'000 * 5'000'000'000 I get this Error:

> System.OverflowException: " value was either too large or too small
>   for an 'int64'."

but its working again when I'm calculating bigger Numbers so that means that dt.Compute() has some problems with multiply some numbers but works with bigger numbers or smaller numbers.

Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Here my Code:

```
string calculation = "500000*5000";
var anwser = dt.Compute(calculation, "");

string str_anwser = anwser.ToString();
RechnerOutput.Text = str_anwser;
```

Comment: From reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2) - the parser makes a guess at the required data size (Int32/Int64) based on the largest value in the expression. When you get too big for Int64 then Double will be used. I am guessing the data type used is based on the input values - not on the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you just can't, Int32 max size **2,147,483,648**
and you multiplication result is **2,500,000,000** which is bigger and will result in the exception you got

A simple trick you can do is to force one of your arguments to be non-int32 number

like so

```
string calculation = "500000*5000.0";
var anwser = dt.Compute(calculation, "");
```

this will result

> 2500000000.0

**Edit:**(as @PaulF said)

The dataSet will try to parse to literals them self in ascending order(int32->int64->double) and **not** the result itself.
meaning if one of the literals is int64(in the case of **5000000000 * 5000000**) then the result may be parsed as **Int64**, but in the first case of **50000*500000** both literals  are **Int32** and so the result will be treated as such

long version From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Integer literals [+-]?[0-9]+ are treated as System.Int32, System.Int64 or System.Double. System.Double can lose precision depending on how large the number is. For example, if the number in the literal is 2147483650, DataSet will first attempt to parse the number as an Int32. This will not succeed because the number is too large. In this case DataSet will parse the number as an Int64, which will succeed. If the literal was a number larger than the maximum value of an Int64, DataSet will parse the literal using Double.

Comment: While your answer works - it doesn't address part of the question which is why do you get an overflow exception with some large values (500000*5000 ), but not even larger values (5000000000 * 5000000).